# jQuery without chain?

Tags: jquery

I know it's possible to write [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) in more JavaScript like syntax rather than the all chain stuff (which is great). It's hard to find a piece of tutorial that provide an understanding for people who want to use less chain-able script, so where I can find any type of tutorial(s)?

While the chain was not bad, it requires a learning curve for being effective & efficient. I have some experience in JavaScript so it would be great if I could re-use my existing knowledge (a.k.a laziness to learn something new on strict and fast moving work environment).

PS: I usually use a less chain framework such as Adobe [Spry Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spry_framework) (dead, sadly), so I hope I could finf some similar approach in writing code on jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Since each part of the chain returns a jQuery object, you can break the chain up into separate pieces.

So, this...

```
$("<div>inner</div>")
    .appendTo("<div>outer</div>")
    .appendTo("body");
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
var myDiv = $("<div>inner</div>");
myDiv.appendTo("<div>outer</div>");
myDiv.appendTo("body");
```

But believe me, once you get used to it, it will become second nature.  Check out [this article](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/26/jQuery-Understanding-the-chain) for some more advice...

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about jQuery is that most functions of the [core jQuery object](http://docs.jquery.com/Core) will return another jQuery object with the same functions available.  So you *can* do this

```
var image = $("#myImage").attr("alt", "The Logo");
image = image.css("logoImage");
```

But it's much easier to do this

```
$("#myImage").attr("alt", "The Logo").css("logoImage");
```

because you cut out the intermediate steps.

It's worth persevering with the chaining, check out the [Getting Started with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It's doubtful you'll find such documentation.

Just replace the chained calls with the proper selectors.

```
$('#myId').call(blah)
          .chain(blah)
          .chain(blah)
```

with

```
var $obj = $('#myId');
$obj.call(blah);
$obj.chain(blah);
...
```

Comment: For complex selectors, you'd want to put the resulting jQuery object in a local variable.  Doing a simple element-by-id selection here is probably fine, but other types could have serious performance hits as well as leaving lots of copy/pasted code.

Comment: I agree. I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Chaining is just using the result of one expression as input in another. They can easily be flattened to separate statements.

In case a method returns the same collection, you can just call the method as any other method:

```
var links = $('a.popup');
var handler = function(e){ window.open(this.href,this.target); e.preventDefault(); };
links.click(handler);
links.css('color', 'red');
```

If a method returns a different collection, you have to assign the return value to a new variable, or back to the same variable replacing the current collection:

```
var links = $('a.popup');
links = links.filter('[target=_blank]');
links.css('font-weight', 'bold');
```