# Can I chain this jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to shorten these jQuery snippets by chaining them together?  For the second chain, I'd like to get rid of the `w` class if possible.

```
$('#content').prepend("<h1 />");
$('#content h1').append( $('#content>p:first strong').html() );
$('#content>p:first strong').parent().remove();

$('font').wrapInner('<p class="w"/>');
$("p.w").unwrap().unwrap();
```

---

**Edit:** Let me clarify my second jQuery snippet.  I'm cleaning up old HTML markup that looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>
        <font>
            <b>Sample Title</b>
            <br>
            More sample text.
        </font>
    </p>
</div>
```

And changing it to this:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>
        <b>Sample Title</b>
        <br>
        More sample text.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: For background on jQuery chaining, see these two stackoverflow questions:


[jQuery chaining: Can everything be chained? When can we not chain?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5505648/) and 


[jQuery without chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912054/)

**In the second article, user James Kolpack includes an off-site link to a simple explanation of jQuery chaining.

Comment: i made it as far as `font` selector and then decided its probably salvageable. Things are bad enough, no amount of clever jquery magic is going to save bad markup.

Comment: @32bitkid - I'm using this jQuery to clean up old markup.  That's why you see the `font` selector.

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do with this:

$('font').wrapInner('<p class="w"/>');
$("p.w").unwrap().unwrap();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
var content = $( '#content' )[0];
var para1 = $( content ).children( 'p' )[0];
var text = $( para1 ).children( 'strong' ).text();

$( '<h1>', { text: text }).prependTo( content );
$( para1 ).remove();
```

---

> As of jQuery 1.4, the second argument to jQuery() can accept a map
>   consisting of a superset of the properties that can be passed to the
>   .attr() method. Furthermore, any event type can be passed in, and the
>   following jQuery methods can be called: val, css, html, text, data,
>   width, height, or offset. The name "class" must be quoted in the map
>   since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and "className" cannot be used
>   since it is not the correct attribute name.

From the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

So, you can pass an object literal as the second argument. That object literal "initializes" the newly created DOM element (the H1 element in our case).

Comment: Can you explain the `, { text: text }` portion of your code?  I haven't found any explanation of arguments used in jQuery selectors.

Comment: I tweaked your suggestion.  Instead of recreating the jQuery objects for each variable, I just kept them: `var $content = $('#content'),  $para1 = $content.children("p:first"), $text = $para1.children("strong").text();`

Answer (score 2):

To cut down processing, you can chain, but it's better to cash the variables (is more readeable).

You can do:

```
var content = $('#content'),
    firstP = $('#content>p:first strong');

content.prepend("<h1 />").find("h1").append( firstP.html() );
firstP.parent().remove();
```

good luck!

Comment: Yup, this is the way to go :)

Comment: *it's "cache", not "cash" - but "cash" would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

the thing about  your code is that you are targeting different selectors,  that's why you would have to modify your selectors, take a look to  [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) that will destroy the last selection filter and you modify your selector

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you'll cut down on processing time by simply chaining that code.
The Rafael.IT answer is good, but I don't think it will help improve the code performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#content')
.prepend("<h1 />");
.find('h1').append( $('#content>p:first strong').html() )
.end()
.find('>p:first strong').parent().remove();

$('font').wrapInner('<p class="w"/>');
$("p.w").unwrap().unwrap();
```

`.end()` ends the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.